# Prisma error when trying to run with elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, prisma

I have a prisma project that works fine locally when I run `$ docker-compose up`.  I converted the `docker-compose.yml` file to `Dockerrun.aws.json`.  But now when i try to run the project locally via `$ eb local run` I get an error

```
mysql_1   | Version: '5.7.24'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
prisma_1  | Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: database - Connection is not available, request timed out after 5001ms.
```

Below is my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file:

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "2",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
    "environment": [
        {
        "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
        "value": "prisma"
        }
    ],
    "essential": true,
    "memory": 128,
    "image": "mysql:5.7",
    "mountPoints": [
        {
        "containerPath": "/var/lib/mysql",
        "sourceVolume": "Mysql"
        }
    ],
    "name": "mysql",
    "portMappings": [
        {
        "containerPort": 3306,
        "hostPort": 3306
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "environment": [
        {
        "name": "PRISMA_CONFIG",
        "value": "port: 4466\ndatabases:\n  default:\n    connector: mysql\n    host: mysql\n    port: 3306\n    user: root\n    password: prisma\n    migrations: true\n"
        }
    ],
    "essential": true,
    "memory": 128,
    "image": "prismagraphql/prisma:1.21",
    "name": "prisma",
    "portMappings": [
        {
        "containerPort": 4466,
        "hostPort": 4466
        }
    ]
    }
],
"family": "",
"volumes": [
    {
    "host": {
        "sourcePath": "mysql"
    },
    "name": "Mysql"
    }
]
}
```

The error message leads me to believe that there's an issue connecting the prisma container to the mysql instance.  If i had to guess it's the PRISMA_CONFIG value but not I'm not 100% sure.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use "PRISMA_CONFIG_PATH" instead and put the yaml into a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have those `/n` in there. YAML cares about real carriage and spaces.